# Printing a different class Array in main function

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop

I would like to ask, is there a way that I am able to print the array in the main function? For example, right now my codes are shown below

```
    Public static void main(String[] args)
{
        mainHobby Hobs = new mainHobby();
        System.out.println("My Hobbies are: ");
        for (int i = 0 ; i<Hobs.size ; i++)
        {
            int num = i + 1;
            System.out.println(num + ": " + Hobs.Hobby[i]);
        }
}

class mainHobby
{
    String[] Hobby = {"Reading", "Swimming", "Running"};
    int size = Hobby.length;
}
```

However, what I am working towards to is printing my Array Hobby under the main function. Printing Array Hobby at the comment portion

```
        Public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            mainHobby Hobs = new mainHobby();
            //Print my array Hobby here
    }

class mainHobby
    {
        String[] Hobby = {"Reading", "Swimming", "Running"};
        int size = Hobby.length;

        System.out.println("My Hobbies are: ");
            for (int i = 0 ; i<Hobs.size ; i++)
            {
                int num = i + 1;
                System.out.println(num + ": " + Hobs.Hobby[i]);
            }
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently? Please show some example output.

Comment: You cannot just define a piece of code whithin a class declaratin. Classes are defined by fields (variables) and method (functions). put your code whithin a method and call it.

Comment: Remember that `main()`, like any other method, must be in a class. As long as you fix that, the first code snippet will work.

Comment: Please stick to the code conventions and write variable names starting with lower-case and class names starting with upper-case. Additionally, please post code that compiles!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
     static class MainHobby{
      String[] hobby = {"Reading", "Swimming", "Running"};
      int size = hobby.length;  

      void printHobby(){

          for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
          {
             System.out.print(hobby[i]+" ");
          }
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainHobby hob = new MainHobby();
        hob.printHobby();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply print your array on the screen by adding the line of code under your main method:

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Hobby);